# Alien probe scans memories and causes (daily) world mind wipe

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to track down a short scifi story I once read. It was about an alien probe scanning the world and accidently erasing 2 days of everyone's memory. So when everyone wakes up on Monday, they're surprised to find that it's actually Wednesday.

Each morning everyone has to re-learn current events to get up to speed. Slowly the world has to rely on retirees as the younger generation forget everything and revert to a younger age.

Comment: Not this, but similar; http://www.amazon.co.uk/Rebirth-Everyone-Classics-Science-Fiction/dp/0883554593

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's Phillip Jose Farmer, ["Sketches Among the Ruins of My Mind"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58168) (summary from [The Official Philip José Farmer Web Page](http://www.pjfarmer.com/WORKS-stories.html)):

> A space ship arrives in our solar system and time starts going
> backwards. People wake up thinking its Wednesday but it is really
> Sunday and they had no memory of the last four days. The next day is
> worse as the same thing happens and they lose four more days. This
> goes on and on as grown people start drooling like babies and are
> unable to take care of themselves. How do the world governments deal
> with the problem and what are the long term affects on society?