# Short story / novella about people losing memory of their last 24 hours memory

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story might be from the 80s or thereabouts. In the story an alien ship goes into orbit around Earth and once a day erases the memories of humans from the last 48? hours.

The result is that everyone thinks it is a day earlier than it actually is, and the next day thinks it is a day earlier than that.

This goes on for 40 years before it ends, so that someone who is 50 when it starts has the memories and mental outlook of a 10-year old, a 60 year old thinks he is 20, etc.

I thought the writer did a good job, given it was a short story, of describing the chaos that results.

Comment: Likely ***Sketches Among The Ruins of My Mind*** By Philip Jose Farmer. A dupe, if my memory (lol) isn't failing me

Comment: Dupe of dupe, in fact; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73797/world-mind-wipe/73816#73816